# Coordinate projection API that accepts HTTP GET requests?

Tags: coordinate-system, software-recommendations, api, curl, http

Is there an API out there that converts/projects coordinates through an HTTP GET request and returns JSON? I imagine the parameters would be something like:

```json
{
  source_epsg: 4326, //WGS84
  target_epsg: 3857, //Web Mercator
  x: x_coord_to_reproject,
  y: y_coord_to_reproject
}
```

Which would be fed into a URL like this:

`https:\\api.anawesomeservice.com/transform?source_epsg=4326&target_epsg=900913&x=x_coord_to_reproject&y=y_coord_to_reproject`

And the output would be something like:

```json
{
  x: x_projected_coord,
  y: y_projected_coord,
  srid: 3857
}
```

I'm only interested in converting point coordinates so far, and ideally the output is JSON so that I can parse it easily and use the results in a Microsoft Power Automate flow.

I'm currently converting between the two listed CRSs, and I understand the math well enough to convert these the "hard way" if need be, but I'm just wondering if there's something useful out there.

Comment: ESRI ArcGIS Online does this inSR=4326 outSR=102113 http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer/project?inSR=4326&outSR=102113&geometries=%7B%0D%0A%22geometryType%22%3A%22esriGeometryPoint%22%2C%0D%0A%22geometries%22%3A%5B%7B%22x%22%3A-117%2C%22y%22%3A34%7D%5D%0D%0A%7D

Comment: I guess this would technically work for my specific use case; however, I wonder if there's something that can handle more CSs?

Comment: ESRI supports most https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/projected-coordinate-systems.htm has a list

Comment: Oh yep, it sure does! not exactly sure what I did wrong in my first test, but it seems to work now. I'd happily accept this as an answer, hopefully ESRI deigns to keep it up for folks.

Answer (score 2):

Why to search for a web service if you can do the conversion locally with for example cs2cs https://proj.org/apps/cs2cs.html or gdaltransform https://gdal.org/programs/gdaltransform.html?

BTW there has been an official code for years for the Web Mercator projection http://epsg.io/3857.

Examples with a point 2 degrees E, 55 degrees N.

```
cs2cs epsg:4326 +to epsg:3857
55 2
222638.98       7361866.11 0.00

gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:3857
2 55
222638.981586547 7361866.11305119 0
```

You notice that the order of the EPSG:4326 coordinates is different for these two utilities.

If you prefer to run cs2cs in the web use https://mygeodata.cloud/cs2cs/.

Comment: Thanks for the official EPSG code, I honestly don't know much about how those work. I need a web service because I'm working with webhooks, so (I think) I need to be able to pass parameters to a URL rather than through a utility/tool in terminal or cmd prompt.